# Denormalization of Data

Tags: r, dataset

For a project I have to denormalize my dataset (actually some more, but when I know, how to do it, I can transfer that). Now it has this structure (I left out the variables in the dataset, I don't need):

```
ID ICD_group year
1  B         2009
1  B         2010
...
1  C         2010
...
2  A         2009
2  A         2010
2  B         2010
...
```

(There are patients, which have been diagnosed in different years with different ICD-Codes)

I need a dataset like this:

```
ID ICD_A ICD_B ICD_C
1   0      1     1
2   1      1     0
```

with Dummy-Variables seeing 1 if there was a diagnosis at least one time and 0 if not.

Comment: you can use the 'cast' / 'dcast' function in the package {reshape2}

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that, but maybe I didn't use the right command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it's pretty straight forward `reshape2::dcast` operation, for example (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID ~ ICD_group, 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) (length(x) > 0) + 0, 
      value.var = "year")    
#   ID A B C
# 1  1 0 1 1
# 2  2 1 1 0
```

You could also try `xtabs` from base R

```
df$indx <- 1
as.data.frame(!!xtabs(indx ~ ID + ICD_group, df)) + 0
#   A B C
# 1 0 1 1
# 2 1 1 0
```

Or just leave it as is

```
(!!xtabs(indx ~ ID + ICD_group, df)) + 0
#    ICD_group
# ID  A B C
#   1 0 1 1
#   2 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the solution I needed!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `table`

```
 (table(df[,-3])>0)+0
 #   ICD_group
 #  ID A B C
 #   1 0 1 1
 #   2 1 1 0
```

If you need a `data.frame`

```
 as.data.frame.matrix((table(df[,-3])>0)+0)
 #  A B C
 #1 0 1 1
 #2 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ICD_group = c("B", 
 "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), year = c(2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2009L, 
 2010L, 2010L)), .Names = c("ID", "ICD_group", "year"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```